# Domino REST Service - Can't get parameter from GET Call

Tags: rest, domino-designer-eclipse

I can't seem to get json handed into a GET call in the serviceBean.

```
    <xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="getaccount">
    <xe:this.service>
    <xe:customRestService requestContentType="application/json" serviceBean="web.service.GetAccount" contentType="application/json"/>
    </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
```

For the pathInfo I've tried pathInfo="getaccount", pathInfo="getaccount/{id}", pathInfo="getaccount{id}"

The serviceBean:

```
    public class GetAccount extends CustomServiceBean {

        @Override
        public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {

            XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, "getAccount()", Level.INFO, null);

            Map parameters = engine.getHttpRequest().getParameterMap();
            XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, "getAccount() - getHttpRequest().getParameterMap(): " + parameters.toString(), Level.INFO, null);

            String json_string = IOUtils.toString(engine.getHttpRequest().getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, "getAccount() - jsonReaderString: " + json_string, Level.INFO, null); }
```

I can get the json_string if I change to a POST, but I should be able to perform a GET and send some json in i.e. { "id": "1234" }

Using SoapUI with the resource as api.xsp/getaccount{id} and a parameter Name=id and Value=1234

Thanks,
Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can use the `engine.getHttpRequest().getRequestURI()`, which will give you the URI handed in e.g. `api.nsf/api.xsp/getaccount/Bob.Smith%40mail.com`. Run a URLDecode to cleanup the encoding.

Hope this helps others trying to sort this out.

Scott.